# ISO Media Videos thumbnails not showing in pop_os 22.04 LTS

Tags: video, ffmpeg, pop-os, nautilus

all videos that are ISO media doesn't have thumbnails.

I have tried the solutions here, but it didn't work (**EDIT:** im a noob, so its possibly those didnt work because im using pop_os distro, and those solutions for debian/ubunto distro.)

[video thumbnails not showing in 20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295397/video-thumbnails-not-showing-in-20-10-hattingokbori87-solution-doesnt-work)

[Any app on Ubuntu to open and/or convert HEIF pictures (.HEIC, High Efficiency Image File Format)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958355/any-app-on-ubuntu-to-open-and-or-convert-heif-pictures-heic-high-efficiency-i/965306#965306)

[How to Display .HEIC thumbnails in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114127/how-to-display-heic-thumbnails-in-nautilus)

[HEIF/HEIC Thumbnail issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299029/heif-heic-thumbnail-issue)

---

I have installed ffmpeg, ffmpegthumbnailer, gstreamer1.0-libav, gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg, libheif1 heif-thumbnailer, libheif1, and heif-gdk-pixbuf ***so far.***

I also tried clearing thumbnail folder in .cache folder, nothing worked.

---

**extra info:
`file filename.xxx` command results of my videos.**

[those are the ones with no thumbnail.]

`filename.mp4: ISO Media, MP4 Base Media v1 [ISO 14496-12:2003]`

`filename.mov: ISO Media, Apple QuickTime movie, Apple QuickTime (.MOV/QT)`

`filename.webm: Matroska data`

[the older webm video i have, with a working thumbnail]

`filename.webm: WebM`

---

**output of** `dpkg -l | grep gstreamer`

[image: gstreamer]

---

**output of** `lsb_release -a`

https://paste.debian.net/hidden/ae855e4d

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Pop
Description:    Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

---

**output of** `apt-cache policy`

https://paste.debian.net/hidden/23fbc927